# Django Please enter either "yes" or "no" not taking answer

Tags: django, django-syncdb

I've just downloaded Django for a school project and our teacher wants us to do the tutorials on their website. I'm following through tutorial 1 and when I call syncdb it creates the admin database. It asks me if I want to create a superuser and I type yes, but it just keeps asking me over and over if I want to. I've reinstalled Django 3 times now and it doesn't make any sense. Im guessing it might have to do with character encoding or something but I haven't been able to find a solution as this problem doesn't seem to come up anywhere on Google.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRdi5.png

As you can see, I'm clearing typing yes correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
python manage.py syncdb --noinput
```

that will just skip the create superuser step of syncdb. If you end up needing a superuser later on, you can use:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```